# How to change the background color of a button that wasn't clicked?

Tags: java, android, button

My goal here is every time a button is clicked the `Button` background colors go back to their default color and the `Button` that is clicked changes color. I'm hoping to do this in `JAVA`, I think a for loop is the way to go but I'm not sure how to edit `Button` that wasn't clicked.

Here is my XML

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/but1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
    android:onClick="buttonOn"
    android:text="Button 1" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/but2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
    android:onClick="buttonOn"
    android:text="Button 2" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/but3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
    android:onClick="buttonOn"
    android:text="Button 3" />
```

Here is my selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/background_blue"
    android:state_pressed="true"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/background_blue"
    android:state_focused="true"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/background_white"/>
</selector>
```

Here is background_white

```
<solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
<padding
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:top="1dp" />
</shape>
```

Here is background_blue

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
<padding
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:top="1dp" />
</shape>
```

Here is my java code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button but1;
    Button but2;
    Button but3;
    Button but4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        but1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but1);
        but2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but2);
        but3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but3);
        but4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but4);
    }

    public void buttonOn(View v) {
        Fragment view;
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.but1:
                Log.i("Button 1", "pressed");
                break;
            case R.id.but2:
                Log.i("Button 2", "pressed");
                break;
            case R.id.but3:
                Log.i("Button 3", "pressed");
                break;
            case R.id.but4:
                Log.i("Button 4", "pressed");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you are getting as an output of the above code?

Comment: You can select the not clicked buttons by ID and set the background.

Comment: I've updated my code to what I'm currently working with but I'm concerned that the log function in JAVA requires two button clicks for the text to print. What can I do to make the log print on one button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add background as a drawable selector to button.Also add android:focusableInTouchMode="true" to make button take touch when pressed.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/but1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
    android:onClick="buttonOn"
    android:text="Button 1" />
```

Then add two drawables for button selected and unselected inside background_selector

**background_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_blue"
android:state_pressed="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_blue"
android:state_focused="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_white"/>
</selector>
```

And then add the background_white and background_blue to drawable folder

**background_white.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />
</shape>
```

**background_blue.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />

   <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: I've tried this code out, but when I run it on my emulator the button don't show up any thought?

Comment: I was able to get this code to work, I do however have a follow-up question. Why do you have to click the button twice before the log.i prints from the java file? I will update my main code.

Comment: like what?you are not able to click button?

Comment: As I said adding android:focusableInTouchMode="true" add touch mode to the button..check this link to know more about the touch mode...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685144/xml-attribute-usage-androidfocusableintouchmode

Answer (score 0):

```
public void changeButtonColors(ViewGroup layout, int clickedButton_id) {
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = layout.getChildAt(i);
            if (v instanceof Button) {
                if (v.getId() == clickedButton_id){
                    ((Button)v).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }else{
                    ((Button)v).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```